# Asserting on case classes in ScalaTest

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, scalatest, case-class

I see there's support for the Option type, but what about custom case classes?

I sort of want to do this:

```
result match {
  case SuccessCase(values) => {
    values.foo should be ("bar")
  }
  case FailureCase => // should fail test, but how to say this in ScalaTest?
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use fail() to fail a test on purpose, as in case FailureCase => fail("err msg"), but I'm not sure I understand what you're after. Perhaps you can show more of the code or elaborate to clarify the question?

Comment: Thanks Bill! And thanks for the brilliant framework. Does my own answer make sense? Pete.

Comment: Ooh, but actually, Inside doesn't help either, because the test doesn't fail if the failure case is not specified. :-( So do I have to explicitly use fail()? I really just want to be able to assert that a case class is a particular case, and extract its contents to make assertions on, a bit like the `option.value` shorthand ... (It might be that I'm missing something obvious!)

Answer (score 2):

Does this work, assuming the case you want is `DesiredCase`?

```
result match {
  case DesiredCase(values) => {
    values.foo should be ("bar")
  }
  case _ => {
    fail("Not DesiredCase")
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, yes, that's what I'm doing (Bill's answer told me how to call fail() explicitly).

Answer (score 0):

Bill Venners also suggested writing a custom matcher if writing these kinds of tests often:

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!msg/scalatest-users/4MemQiqLzao/_DsBTQWaqfwJ